# No controls in emulator?

Tags: android

I'm trying to run a very simple Android demo using the eclipse ADT.  The app compiles & the emulator opens but no controls show up.  I have a title for the app, but the button & text field do not display.  Any ideas?  I don't see any errors in the console.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send" 
        android:onClick="sendMessage"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: did you call setContentView() from whichever Activity you're displaying?

Comment: That was it...thanks.  But why doesn't the official Android tutorial mention that? . I know I'm only on the beginning lesson, but I'd think Google would give you working code samples.

Comment: I rarely use Google's "samples" they feel incomplete for me as they do very small implementation. Vogella is wonderful for Android tuts though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `setContentView (R.layout.yourLayout);` This method inflates your layout file and allows it to be displayed within your Activity.